# Sort a nested list by two elements

Tags: python, list, sorting

Let's say I have a list like below:

```
[['Harry', '4'], ['Anthony', '10'], ['Adam', '7'], ['Joe', '6'], ['Ben', '10']]
# we can say the first element in it's lists is `name`, the second is `score`
```

I want sort it to:

```
[['Anthony', '10'], ['Ben', '10'], ['Adam', '7'], ['Joe', '6'], ['Harry', '4']]
```

So first sort it in descending order by the score and then sort it in ascending order by the name.

---

I've tried:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), x[0]))
[['Harry', '4'], ['Joe', '6'], ['Adam', '7'], ['Anthony', '10'], ['Ben', '10']]
```

It's working, so now I just need reverse it:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), x[0]), reverse=True)
[['Ben', '10'], ['Anthony', '10'], ['Adam', '7'], ['Joe', '6'], ['Harry', '4']]
```

Ah, `reverse=True` simply reversed the list but didn't give the expect output. So I just want reverse the output of `int(x[1])`, but not `x[0]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-int(x[1]), x[0]))
[['Anthony', '10'], ['Ben', '10'], ['Adam', '7'], ['Joe', '6'], ['Harry', '4']]
```

Basically, by changing the sign of the score part of the key, the sort keys will be:

```
(-10, 'Anthony'),
(-10, 'Ben'),
(-7, 'Adam'),
(-6, 'Joe'),
(-4, 'Harry')
```

And so, with `(a, b) < (c, d) <=> (a < c) or (a == c and b < d)`, you end up with your desired sorting order.